# RunWorkerCompleted firing too fast

Tags: c#, .net, events, backgroundworker

i got some really simple code, but cant get it to work. I'm using BackgroundWorker. Problem is that RunWorkerCompleted is fired way to fast. Instantly after running  i get message "Work completed", but application remains frozen for couple of seconds as 'DataType data = new DataType(path);' is beign executed. After that i got all my DataGridViews etc filled correctly. If i swap this single line with Thread.Sleep everything seems to work well. Any ideas?

```
    public frmWindow(string path)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataType d;
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(path);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       string path = e.Argument as string;
       DataType data = new DataType(path);
       e.Result = data;            
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       d = e.Result as DataType;
       MessageBox.Show("Work completed");
    }
```

Comment: At what point are you updating the UI? Its not clear from the code.  If the app is hanging its likely to be on the UI thread, e.g. that part tha populates your gridview, which presumably runs outside of the background worker.

Comment: You mention a line in DoWork when you talk about RunWorkerCompleted - which is it?

Comment: `After that i got all my DataGridViews etc filled correctly`.  So filling the grids is taking the time, not the DoWork() method.

Comment: RobJohnson - above code is part of new Form which is displayed after user select file for processing. It has progress bar and such stuff, and when it finish processing it returns DataType to main form. After receiving that main form continue with UI update. So to sum up: I select file on main form, then new form with backgroudnworker is displayed. Instantly after that RunWorkerCompleted is fired (I can see message box), auxiliary form closes, main form freezes for 15 secs and after that i get UI update with loaded data.

Comment: Okay. "DataType data = new DataType(path)" does a lot of processing and takes about 15secs to complete with my test file. Then i suppose that RunWorkerCompleted will be fired after mentioned 15 secs. Instead i got instant message "Work completed" and app freeze for 15 secs, that's why i'm assuming that mentioned data are still beign processed. In that case, why did RunWorkerCompleted fired?

Hans - thanks but i'm sure that's not it. After processing there's really not much to display on datagridviews so it's impossible it takes so long.

Comment: Hmm maybe add break points to the 'do work' and 'run worker completed' methods and see exactly what is going on.  If the break point in your completed method is hit while you are still stepping through 'do work' then there is something wrong with how these event handlers have been assigned.  Otherwise it should give you clarity on what exactly is happening, perhaps 'new DataType(path)' is executing instantly or firing off a new thread or something.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use Debug.Write instead of MessageBox.Show with timers to show when the Methods are entered and exited.

While it is possible for this same background thread to act on your UI, its almost always NOT a good thing to do--UI is not threadsafe.

```
BackgroundWorker backGroundWorker1;
        public frmWindow(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataType d;

            backGroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

            backGroundWorker1.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Work started at: " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
                string path = e.Argument as string;
                DataType data = new DataType(path);
                e.Result = data;
            };

            backGroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                d = e.Result as DataType;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Work completed at: " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            };

            backGroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
```